# Datediff, how to not include start date that's in the future

Tags: sql, t-sql

My current query is

```
case when datediff(day, isnull(installment_duedate, due_date), getdate()) < 30 
then amount_due else 0 end as [unpaid under 30 days]
```

I have another 3 case that does between 30-60 days, between 60-90s and greater then 90 days.

My current problem is, my installment_duedate has future dates in it.  If someone has an installment due date it would be something like **12-02-2012, 03-02-2013, 06-02-2013, 09-02-2013**. If it's in the future I would like it to return as 0 for now but currently the amount is showing up in my under 30 days.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: i think you meant past dates and not future dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your case to:

```
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, ISNULL(installment_duedate, due_date), GETDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 30
     THEN amount_due ELSE 0 END AS [unpaid under 30 days]
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be it!

Answer (score 2):

In this line , when installment_duedate is past date , [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) returns negative value which is less than  30 and hence `< 30` condition gets satisfied

```
datediff(day, isnull(installment_duedate, due_date), getdate()) < 30
```

**Format**

```
DATEDIFF(datepart,startdate,enddate)
```

for solution to it , see **Lamak's** answer below